# appengine.google.com & objectify - working ok locally but not on gae?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I am developing a backend using Android Studio and Java.
I use objectify to manipulate entities in Google's Datastore.

The question is the following: everything works ok locally. I can call any of the endpoint and add, update and delete entities. However, anything to do with the same entities do not seem to work on GAE... Is there anything specific required for this to work?

Logs are fairly limited also but it appears all endpoints register properly.

The only thing meaningful out of the GAE and logs section is for return calls being set to 200 but nothing more....

Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it "does not seem to work" ? Does it work with the API explorer ? The 200 response might be normal, check the inside of the response for more info.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information on how it doesn't seem to work. Are the entities not updating (check the Datastore viewer)? Have you put in any of your own logging?

Comment: The only issue I faced when uploading the app is for guava and objectify jars not being stored in the right directory. There were messages saying it could not find those specific classes. After few clicks and research on the internet it recommended to move those jars under WEB-INF/lib. This fixed this error message so I assume everything is working properly. However, I still cannot get a single entity created. My end points all have logging in place for now but no logging is actually showing in the GAE console. I'll check the inside of the response and will add an update.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the google public issue tracker and saw your code posted [there](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11282) (I am also editing your answer to add said code).  I can't help but notice that in your "test.html", you load the function from "localhost:8080".  This will obviously break your code whenever you're using it on a client's machine, because it will try to load the function from HIS localhost, which won't have your function in it.

When you're running your code on your production server, you would need to use something like "your-end-point.your-application.appspot.com" to get your function.

Also, I think that you can ONLY pass around either JSON or "[JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)" object.  And it seems the "Test" you are passing isn't a JavaBeans (it has a constructor with at least a parameter).

The fact it never loads the function properly could also explain why your Logs don't show.